# Github for windows client "failed to load commit history for this repository"

Tags: github

!
2014-01-04 20:18:46.9614|INFO|thread:1|GitHub.ViewModels.RepositoryViewModel|Refresh of Git data skipped b/c sync is in progress
2014-01-04 20:18:48.7575|INFO|thread:1|GitHub.Extensions.ReactiveScreen|Deactivating GitHub.ViewModels.ShellViewModel.
2014-01-04 20:18:48.7575|INFO|thread:1|GitHub.Extensions.ReactiveScreen|Deactivating GitHub.ViewModels.RepositoryViewModel.
2014-01-04 20:18:48.7685|INFO|thread:1|GitHub.Extensions.ReactiveScreen|Closed GitHub.ViewModels.RepositoryViewModel.

here is my "TheLog" file ,thank you for you help!